# How to correctly parse an array for an SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

When you need to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE id in (18,2,6,4,5)
```

And the id array comes from another query like:

```
$ids = $conn->fetchAll('SELECT origin from action WHERE url = "'.$url.'" AND SUBSTRING(origin,1,3)<>"pct" GROUP BY origin');
```

If I need to parse the array in order to give the right format to the query id do:

```
    $norm_ids = '(';
    foreach ($ids as $ids) {
        $norm_ids .= $ids['origin'] .',';
    }
    $norm_ids = substr_replace($norm_ids ,"",-1) .')';
```

That outputs the ids like: `(id1,id2,id3,id.......)`, so the I'll just: `FROM userinfo WHERE id in ". $norm_ids`;

But seems to ugly to me, is there a way to do this better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
$idStr = rtrim(str_repeat('?,', count($ids), ',');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE id in (' . $idStr . ')';
```

and then use [`prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

```
$conn = $db->prepare($query);
$conn->execute($ids);
$res = $conn->fetchAll(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE id IN (SELECT origin from action ......) ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the id's separate or can you combine them into 1 query?

perhaps something like:

```
SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE id in (SELECT origin from action WHERE url = "'.$url.'" AND SUBSTRING(origin,1,3)<>"pct" GROUP BY origin');
```

this way you let the sql server do the work.

Answer (score 1):

When i am faced with such situations, i use trim

```
$norm_ids_str = '';
foreach ($ids as $ids) {
    $norm_ids_str .= $ids['origin'] .',';
}
$norm_ids = '(' . trim($norm_ids_str, ',') . ')';
```